# C++ Getting number of bytes read by a function

Tags: c++, linux, g++

Is there a way to get number of bytes read by the function ?

Using function `**getrusage**` I can get the count of

```
 ru_inblock;       /* block input operations */
```

But how to get number of bytes read by function ?

Comment: with the information given, i make a guess: get the count of "ru_inblock" and multiply it by the blocksize?^^

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You will need to preload your own SO that overrides `read(2)` which calls it and counts how many bytes are actually read.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strace(1)` or a debugger. You will have to postprocess the output a bit, but all the information about the data transferred by syscalls is there.

Comment: @forko It is there way to do grouping by function from strace ? I didn't find any way to do that.